# Question about JFET resistor connection

Tags: jfet

[image: Photovoltaic MOSFET driver]

In the picture is a Photovoltaic mosfet driver. So I understand that the JFET is used to discharge the MOSFET gate to source capacitance to decrease its turn of time. Whats the function of the 2M resistor ?, they dont say how its calculated. If its a bleeder resistor then shouldnt it be connected from gate to source like below?

[image]

Comment: It is. Note the difference between the two FETs.

Comment: I guess one is pchannel and the other is nchannel, ok thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In the p-channel JFET there is a PN junction across the source-gate terminal. This junction has a very low capacitance. When the voltage on the gate falls to zero, the gate-source capacitor, namely Cgs, starts to discharge through the 2M ohms resistor.

[image]

Then the charge quickly disappears and JFET starts to conduct. This will turn off the MOSFETs.

Comment: How would one calculate a sutiable value for this bleed resistor? I believe it needs to be large enough so that current is taken from the JFET gate rather than MOSFET gates during turn-off. But, using a lower value causes a faster bleed (it should also improve turn-on time, but that's a separate issue). Since there's no explicit resistance in series with the JFET gate, it seems like the bleed resistor could be made quite a bit smaller. Am I missing something here?